Is this a good method to access a logging object across modules?
When using Python's built-in logging module, I see most examples access the log using something like log = logging.getLogger('SomeName'), across different modules/files in a program. You can do this to get the same object each time without requiring the logger to reinitialize new instances.
But I fail to see why it's done this way, because it seems like there's a simpler and more efficient method (albeit only slightly) by taking advantage of how module imports work.
For example, I have a custom logger in Logger.py, and at the end of that file I declare log = CustomLogger() (as a global variable in that file). Now, in any other file that I want to log from, I can import that with from Logger import log and use it as normal (e.g. log.info('test')). After the first time that module is imported it's cached, and subsequent imports in other files will not require the logger to be reinitialized, or re-run any loose code in that module (for example, you can see this if you put a print statement in a module and try to import it several times).
Furthermore, many logging examples actually use log = logging.getLogger(__name__) across different modules, in which case it will create a new, different logger each time that line appears. With the previous methods, the logger is already able to determine what module it's logging from (if you want to include module in your log messages), and this must be less efficient than both, so what's the benefit of this?
So the three methods I'm looking at here are:

logging.getLogger('SomeName')
from Logger import log
logging.getLogger(__main__)

To give a simplified example of my method (#2):
main.py:
from Logger import log
import module1

def main():
    log.info( 'Starting' )
    module1.runCode()
    log.info( 'Done' )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Logger.py:
import logging

class CustomLogger( logging.Logger ):
    def __init__( self, name, level=logging.DEBUG ):
        super().__init__( name, level )
        self.fileHandler = FileHandler( "log.txt", mode='w', encoding='utf-8' )
        self.fileHandler.setLevel( level )
        self.addHandler( self.fileHandler )

log = CustomLogger( 'SomeName' )

module1.py:
from Logger import log

def runCode():
    log.info( 'Doing things' )

Ultimately, my question is what's the best way to do this, and why? Is there any downside to my method of from Logger import log?

Python's logging library uses the Singleton design pattern - which means that any call to logging.getLogger(name) will create the logger if it hasn't done so already and return it, thus always returning a reference to the same logger, assuming the name field is the same. Your "import" way of doing things is not necessary, as the same behavior occurs "under the hood", so to speak.
TLDR; If you use the same name, or don't pass a name, it will return the same logger, even across modules. You can make module-specific loggers by calling "logging.getLogger(__name__)".

Yeah, I'm aware that I would get the same object back. But so would the from Logger import log method. And I don't know what exactly goes on when calling the .getLogger() method, but I would guess it's more complex (less efficient or slower) than simply doing an import, right? So I'm just not sure what the benefit is.

Unsure what the performance difference would be, if any, as they are just two ways of returning a reference to the same object. Typically libraries have built-in optimizations and reasoning for these kinds of design choices, so I would advise you to allow yourself to use the built-in behavior.
